# 「助言」と「示唆」はどう違いますか。

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

最近、「示唆」という言葉を学びました。意味的にsuggestionという意味だそうですが、「助言」と同じ意味ではないでしょうか。それぞれのニュアンス何ですか。

その違いが分かるように色々な例文を探してみました:

> **助言**を受ける人。
> 彼の**助言**は非常に役立つ。
> 牧師としての**助言**。

> この結果はそのような可能性を**示唆**している。
> 解決すべき課題の**示唆**。
> その提案は**示唆**に富んでいる。

その例文を参考にして、次の点に気が付きました:

1. 「言」の漢字が含むので、確かに「助言」は人が言ってるものです。
2. 「示唆」も人が言ってるアドバイス時も使えるかもしれませんが、それ以外も使うことがあります。
3. 「示唆」はimplication, hint, sign、すなわち、結果や実験で何か事実あることも表します。

合ってますか。「助言」と「示唆」の使い分けを教えていただけませんか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問者の考えておられる通りで，例文も良いものを集めておられると思います．

国語辞書をひいてみると，次のとおり説明されています．

- 助言

  - かたわらから言葉を添えて助けること．また，その言葉．（広辞苑）
  - かたわらからことばを添えて助けること．また，そのことば．（精選版日本国語大辞典）
  - わきから役に立つような言葉を添えて助けること．また，そのことば．（明鏡）
  - 助けになるような意見や言葉を，そばから言ってやること．また，その言葉．（デジタル大辞泉）
- 示唆

  - それとなく気づかせること．また暗にそそのかすこと．（広辞苑）
  - 他の物事によって，それとなく教え示すこと．また，その教え．（精選版日本国語大辞典）
  - それとなく教え示すこと．ほのめかすこと．（明鏡）
  - それとなく知らせること．ほのめかすこと．（デジタル大辞泉）

この通り，助言は，誰かが言葉で，例えば人にこうするといいよと教えて，助けることを意味します．実験の結果のおかげで次に考えるべきことが明らかになっても，それは結果から助言されたとは言いません（擬人化していない限りは）．また，誰かが態度で何かを教えてくれる時も，普通は助言とは言わないと思います．Advice が近いです．

一方，示唆は，(1) はっきり言葉で示すとは限らない，(2) 助けることよりも示すことに重点がある，ことに違いがあると思います．

1. 人が何かを「示唆する」という場合は，直接的でなく何かを述べる，という意味であることが多いです．

- ニュースで，[中国が対抗措置を示唆](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20230403/k10014028041000.html) したというときは，具体的にこのようにするという声明ではなくて，もう少し抽象的に（「黙って見過ごすことなく断固とした対応をとる」）予告しています．また，助けるニュアンスはありません．
- たとえば，「〇〇先生には研究にあたって多くの貴重な示唆をいただきました」という文では，具体的な指示ではなく，ヒントをもらったりして自分の考えを進められた，ということです．「助言」を使っても良いですが，強いて使い分けるとしたら，助言のほうが具体的な内容ということになるかもしれません．

2. 物が何かを「示唆する」という場合は，おっしゃるとおり，結果からなにかの事実や可能性が，直接的でなくても示されるということです． 挙げておられる， imply, hint, signify, が近いと思います．上に書いた辞書の定義はこちらをあまり重視していないように見えますが，普通に使う表現です．

- 確定的に明らかなことには使いません．例えば，ある実験結果から，より大きな仮説が支持されそうなときにはそれを「示唆する」と言えますし，油が水に浮くことがわかったので油の比重が水より軽いことが示唆される，といっても良いが，水の比重と油の比重を実際に測定したときに，油のほうが軽いと示唆された，とは言わないと思います．また，頑張って計算したところ，54824*43531 が 2386543544 であると示唆される，とは言いません．

3. こうした意味を含めて，「Aが直接示すわけではないが，Aから考えられる色々なこと」を指すことがあります．示唆に富む，などはこうした表現です．

じつは， suggest の方も，辞書を引くと概ね2つにわけて説明されることが多いようです．Oxford dictionary of Engilsh (電子辞書に入っているもので，詳しい版はわかりませんが)

Sugggest:

1. [reporting verb] put forward for consideration
2. [with obj.] cause one to think that (something) exists or is the case

このうち　1. が助言や提案にちかく， 2. が示唆に近い，といえます．